# How to capture command output from command waiting for input?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a command that I want to parse.  However, this command, in certain scenarios, will prompt if it needs user-intervention (e.g. yes/no, [enter] to continue, etc.).  How to I capture the output from this command while showing all the output?  If the command waits for input, it'll look like the command is busy executing when it's really at a prompt.

```
$ program_output=$(command)
  # Program stalls here performing a `read` but user doesn't see anything
  # User finally presses [Enter]
$

$ command
  Warning: Some warning message.  Continue? (Y/n)
  Y  #User-input
  Created http://example/subprogram/id/
$
```

Comment: Would it be ok for you to redirect the output of the command to a file? In that case you could use the `tee` command so that the user also sees the output and it is stored to a file.

Comment: I would need to handle the command being executed concurrently by different people.  Should I simply get the process id and use that as part of the file descriptor?

Comment: In general, best practice is for programs *not* to unconditionally prompt from stdin. For instance, most of your OS package managers can have answers to all their possible prompts fed in through environment variables or command-line arguments, making this kind of issue entirely moot.

Comment: Are you in control of the command, or only the script trying to parse it? If the latter, you might want to look at the program [`expect`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) or one of the alternatives listed on that page.

Comment: (Many programs will also automatically use a default rather than prompting if stdin is not a TTY -- if you run them with stdin redirected `</dev/null`, for example).

Comment: I've written the script that parses it.  I have no control over `command` nor does it give me much flexibility.
IMHO it's a poorly written CLI for a GUI program.  I'm using it to automate certain tasks.  If I could rewrite it I would.  Since it's not my command and it maybe updated in the future, I just want to automate around it and allow it to prompt if it needs to.

Comment: Could you do something with an expect script? I haven't used it myself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are capturing stdout, you could print a message on stderr to provide feedback:

```
echo -n 'Warning: Some warning message.  Continue? (Y/n) ' >&2
read -r answer
```

Comment: I don't know what messages to expect.  `command` is essentially a black box.  I want to handle prompts dynamically rather than assuming.